# creating directory from filename and move bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a load of files

```
BR0200.aaa.tsv
BR0200.bbb.tsv
BR0200.ccc.tsv
BR0210.aaa.tsv
BR0210.bbb.tsv
BR0210.ccc.tsv
W0210.aaa.tsv
W0210.aaa.tsv
W0210.aaa.tsv
```

I would like to create a series of directories based on the first part of the filename up to the first '.'

```
BR0200
BR210
W0210
```

and then move the associated files to the correct directories (i.e. all BR0200.* files to BR0200 directory).

I have had a stab at a bash script but I keep getting errors. Any advice would be gratefully received.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in BR* W0*; do
dir = "${file%%.*}"
if [-e $dir];then
mv "$file" "$dir"
else
mkdir -p "$dir"
mv "$file" "$dir"
fi
done
```

Sorry if this is a basic question. I have tried searching the web, but with no result.

Comment: @owlstead globbing is one of the most useful features that shells have to offer.

Comment: @jordanm you are right of course, removing comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no whitespace allowed around the `=` in an assignment.

```
dir="${file%%.*}"
```

Conversely, whitespace is *required* in a test.

```
if [ -e $dir ]; then
    ^       ^
```

As far as stylistic improvements, it doesn't hurt to do an unnecessary `mkdir -p`, so you can get rid of the `if` statement.

Quotes aren't required in an assignment, so you can remove them from the `dir=` line. Quoting is a good idea everywhere else though, so don't delete the other quotes.

It might be good to add an extra `.*` to the for loop. That way if you run the script more than once it won't try to move those newly-created sub-directories. And a neat trick (though not necessarily an improvement) is to shorten `BR*.* W0*.*` to `{BR,W0}*.*`.

```
for file in {BR,W0}*.*; do
    dir=${file%%.*}
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
for file in BR* WO*
do
dir=$(echo ${file} | awk -F. '{print $1}' OFS=.)
mkdir $dir
mv $file $dir
done
```

I had a similar situation and this worked for me.